# How to restrict calls to api rest

Tags: javascript, android, ios, api, express

Firstly, sorry for the format of this question. I know the rules for this site, but I haven't previous work nor investigation, because, basically, I don't know where to start...

I'm content with a tip for I start.

I'm searching how restrict calls to an api rest made in expressjs from (only) a native mobile app (ios and android). I thinking in a token, but I don't think it's a very safe idea, because any people can take the token and simulate to be the mobile app, or I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot restrict access to a REST api from only a native mobile app.  The internet is wide open for access from any client so if you have a REST server, then any client can access it, whether mobile or not.

You can control access via authentication.  So, usually what one would do is to require some sort of account access and then have your server watch for unexpected or unauthorized use and, if found, you disable that account.

You could also embed "secret" credentials in your mobile app and use those as the authorization over SSL, but a determined hacker could still get the credentials out of your app if they wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't restrict a public REST Api. Any request that your mobile users send can also be send by anyone.

Maybe you can keep a 'secret' string and attcah to http requests, but it can be easily exposed by sniffing http traffic or decompiling the apk.

Your last option is restricting access by IP, but I don't know if it's suitable with your case.

Answer (score 1):

Of cource any one can simulate any APIs, it would just need a sniffer and the understanding of the right data format (like the format of the JSON object that is sent by your client app).

Anyone can go ahead, figure out how the WhatsApp works and simulate such an app. This can even happen when you are getting each user to `Sign up` first, then the "simulator" will just have to simulate that process too.

But, generally, what a developer wants is that :

1. People use his app
2. People use his REST APIs

Point 1 implies Point 2, but Point 2 does not imply Point 1. You cannot stop a hacker or someone from using your APIs without your App, you can just slow his simulator-development-process using some techniques.

Then you might ask, cant he flood your server with millions of request ? Of course he can. That a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). In theory, he can even use manny android simulators and install your App and then flood your server with millions of request.

Any one can use your APIs if you open it to the internet world.